# Removing query parameter using node.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having this code to remove a query parameter from a url, but it is not working. Can you have a look please?

```js
const url = require('url')

const obj = url.parse('http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1&query2=val2', true)
delete obj.query.query2
const link = url.format(obj)
console.log(link) // I was expecting the removal of query2 but it didn't happen
```

It logged the same url as was passed above, why `query2` is not removed? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make `link` to be `http://www.example.com/path?query2=val2`

Comment: @D-reaper looks to me, like he is trying to make it `http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1` rather than 2

Comment: @D-reaper other way around, removing `query2` altogether. @OP To delete a key-value pair you need to do `delete object.obj['key'];`, I've had a look at restructuring the URL but no dice. The above will remove `query2` from the `query` object though.

Comment: yes, trying to remove `query2` and wanna retain `query1`

Comment: Oh yes my bad, so `http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1` it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove search node from object

```
const obj = url.parse('http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1&query2=val2', true)
delete obj.query.query2
delete obj.search

const link = url.format(obj)
console.log(link)
```

This will return you url http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1

Answer (score 1):

Even though you delete `query2` from query object, `query2` is still present in search field.

```
const url = require('url');

const obj = url.parse('http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1&query2=val2', true)
console.log(obj);
delete obj.query.query2
delete obj.search
console.log(obj);
const link = url.format(obj)
console.log(link)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at through the source for url module (https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url/blob/master/url.js).  You can see that 
it will look at the search node first (line 413).  Remove this as well, so that the query object is evaluated.

delete obj.search;

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = require("url")

const urlObj = url.parse('http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1&query2=val2', true)

delete urlObj.query.query2
delete urlObj.search

const newUrl = url.format(urlObj)

console.log(newUrl) // print >> http://www.example.com/path?query1=val1
```